# Ruby convert string to keyword argument

Tags: ruby, arguments, keyword, tostring

I have a function in ruby that takes keyword arguments in the following form:

```
def get_customer_information(name: nil, dob: nil, age: nil, state: nil)
   ... query db based on supplied parameters
end
```

The user can specify 1 to all of the keyword arguments. There is also a command line interface where the user can leverage this function by calling a command line call and passing in a key/value of information of the following form:

```
>GetCustomerInformation name=myName, dob=myDOB
```

The parameters are parsed and separated into keys and values. However, I need to know which keyword argument is associated with the supplied input from the command line. Is there a way to convert a string to a keyword argument (for example, convert name to name:) so that I need not perform string comparison on each parameter to determine which keyword argument it is associated with, resulting in a call of the form:

```
get_customer_information(name.to_keyword myName, dob.to_keyword myDOB)
```

Or is this not possible in ruby?

Comment: Looking for `.to_sym`? http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-to_sym

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *.to_sym* method. This is ruby function method that convert string to symbol.

Or using rails own, *"symbol name".parameterize.underscore.to_sym*. This will convert the string to *:symbol_name*. This uses rails naming convention.

Comment: I'm getting an error doing the work like so (string parsing already done): name = name.to_sym, dob = dob.to_sym, and calling the function as: get_customer_information(name myName, dob myDOB). Is there a difference between symbol and keyword in ruby since .to_sym gives me :name, and the keyword I generally pass in is name: 'value'?

Comment: try making it `get_customer_information(name => myName, dob => myDOB)` (notice the hash rockets). `.to_sym` converts "dob" to :dob (looks like you're expecting dob:).

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to use keyword arguments (unsure if the hash rockets also equate to keyword arguments, still new to ruby). I was able to utilize the .to_sym method while keeping the keyword arguments by use .to_sym in a hash. For example: get_customer_information({name.to_sym => myName, dob.to_sym => myDOB}). Which may be the equivalent of your suggestion. Thanks for the help!